# Auto-renewable Subscriptions an unknown error occurred

Tags: ipad, ios, subscription

In my iPad application I used to use old model for subscriptions and I made it work just fine. Since last Tuesday (15th Feb. 2011) Apple introduced a new model for subscriptions: auto-renewable.

After creating a product in iTunes Connect for the new type of subscription and replacing it with old one, I am experiencing an unknown error. To be more specific the whole transaction goes well, the user can confirm buying product, but then the transaction is not processed at all and is failing with pop-up:

> An unknown error occurred. Retry. Cancel

I've searched the web for some solutions, but all of them are about cases of using old model for subscription. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article on [Invalid Product IDs](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/). While it doesn't specifically address your error. I would bet the steps it suggests you take are likely to clear up your problem.